# Show a WordPress page in a subdomain without redirecting

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a WordPress site that has a page with url: `mysite.com/ads`

I would like to setup a subdomain and when people go to `ads.mysite.com` they see the content of `mysite.com/ads` without changing the url (without redirecting).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Ajax to load the page asynchronously (without being redirected).

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body".load("mysites.com/ads"));
   });
</script>
```

But the URLs in the newly loaded page would not be changed. You can change them using jquery too.